# Metadata extraction from Revit/ IFC models

Tags: oauth, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-designautomation, autodesk-data-management

I am a new user and may I ask any suggestion!!!
How could I extract metadata information of a Revit objects (like Column / Beam / Wall) from Revit and IFC models ?
I search the metadata topic in this forum, but I could not find.

My desire metadata information is Extruted Direction XYZ, Object Shape Information (like Clipping / CSG / Brep / Swept solid).
PLease instruct me any sources and information. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Autodesk Platform Services and Revit API!

You have two options:

- Install Revit on your Windows desktop PC, run it locally, implement a Revit add-in and use the built-in [.NET Revit API](https://www.autodesk.com/developer-network/platform-technologies/revit)
- Make use of the cloud-based Autodesk Platform Services (formerly Forge) and their [Design Automation API for Revit](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/overview/)